# async parallel with variadic callback

Tags: javascript, async.js

I wasn't really happy with this code:

```
async.parallel([
  getThing1,
  getThing2,
  getThing3
], function(err, responses) {
  next.ifError(err);

  var thing1 = responses[0],
      thing2 = responses[1],
      thing3 = responses[2];

  // business
});
```

I'd prefer it to look like this, à la require:

```
async.parallel([
  getThing1,
  getThing2,
  getThing3
], function(err, thing1, thing2, thing3) {
  next.ifError(err);

  // business
});
```

This is what I've ended up with:

```
async.variadic = function(fn) {
  return function(err, responses) {
    return fn.bind(this, err).apply(this, responses);
  }
}

async.parallel([
  getThing1,
  getThing2,
  getThing3
], async.variadic(function(err, thing1, thing2, thing3) {
  next.ifError(err);

  // business
}));
```

Questions:

Am I using `this` correctly in `fn.bind(this, err).apply(this, responses);`?

Is there an existing way to do this with the async library?

---

Update: Here's a different way to accomplish this:

```
async.variadic = (function() {
  var _async = {};
  _async.prototype = async;
  _async.parallel = function(tasks, callback) {
    return async.parallel(tasks, function(err, responses) {
      return callback.bind(this, err).apply(this, responses);
    });
  };
  return function() {
    return _async;
  };
})();

async.variadic().parallel([
  getThing1,
  getThing2,
  getThing3
], function(err, thing1, thing2, thing3) {
});

I think I like this one most. Is this a good way to accomplish the task?
```

---

Here's a jsperf with a different idea: http://jsperf.com/variadic-async

Comment: Using `.apply`, at least until ES6 is probably your best and only bet to convert a function with an array param to a function that takes varargs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I personally prefer the first approach. The `variadic` function knows less about what's going on and could be abstracted even more :

```
function variadic(fn) {
  var self = this;
  return function(err, responses) {
    responses.unshift(err);
    return fn.apply(self, responses);
  }
}

async.variadic = variadic.bind(async);

async.parallel([
    function(cb) {
      cb(null,'1')
    },
    function(cb) {
      cb(null,'2')
    },
    function(cb) {
      cb(null,'3')
    },
], async.variadic(function(err, thing1, thing2, thing3) {
    console.log(this);
    console.log(thing1,thing2,thing3);
  // business
}));
```

Comment: I'll add your implementation to the jsperf. But, you can see the existing jsperf where I did array manipulation, it was much much slower than `bind(err).apply(results)`

Comment: Interestingly I'm getting really sporadic results on the updated jsperf. Your implementation comes out pretty near the top though. Great work and thanks for the help. I'm going to add some tests around this and submit a PR to the async lib.

Comment: Not sure how i feel about mutating the `responses` array though